# Getting an array name from a searched value

Tags: javascript, json

I'm basically trying to have some code look for a specific JSON string in a JSON file and report back what the parent name of it is. I'm using NodeJS for this.

For example:

```
{
    "Array1" : [
        "Thing1",
        "Thing2",
        "Thing3",
     ],
     "Array2" : [
     "Thing4",
     "Thing5",
     "Thing6"
     ]
}
```

What I want this code to do is take a value I give it, e.g "Thing1", and report back with the name of the array it is in, so, I get it to search for "Thing1" and it gives me back "Array1". I get it to search for "Thing4" and it comes back with "Array2". The output it gives needs to be in a variable for me to use later on in my code.

Thanks for any help!
Cheers,
Nathan.

Comment: Have you tried anything?
Is duplication possible, and if so what's the expected output? (Array1 and Array2 have the same value)

Comment: I've mainly been scrawling through forums to try and find the answer currently. I'm not amazing at JS so I've not tried anything yet as I've had absolutely no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
function search(arr,searchStr)
{
for( a in arr)
 if(arr[a].filter(t=>t==searchStr).length>0)
    return a;
 return null;
}
```

And

```
search(yourArray,'Thing1');
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I am a bit late to the party here, but I think in ES6 you can also do it in a more "function" way:

```
const search = (obj, value) => Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k].includes(value));
```

and then you can do this:

```
search(obj, 'Thing1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {
    "Array1" : [
        "Thing1",
        "Thing2",
        "Thing3",
     ],
     "Array2" : [
     "Thing4",
     "Thing5",
     "Thing6"
     ]
};

const find = (obj, search) => {
    const result = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
        if (obj[key].filter(thing => thing === search).length > 0) 
            return key;
        return null;
    }).filter(result => result != null);
    if (result.length > 0) {
        return result[0];
    }
    return null;
}

const array = find(obj, "Thing1");
console.log(array);
```